# Julian calendar for a UK locale in ncal

Tags: locale, cal

On my machine, ncal identifies my country code as GB, and use that to find the date for the shift to the gregorian calendar, and I think cal uses the same date by default:

cal:

```
$ cal 09 1752

   September 1752     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2 14 15 16  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

ncal:

```
$ ncal 09 1752

    September 1752    
Mo    18 25         
Tu  1 19 26         
We  2 20 27         
Th 14 21 28         
Fr 15 22 29         
Sa 16 23 30         
Su 17 24
```

However, when I switch ncal to old, cal-style output, this disappears:

```
ncal -b 09 1752

   September 1752     
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Is this intended? The same happens when specifying different country codes in ncal..

[edit] added command lines used.

Comment: Ahh sorry forgot that. Added now.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code, the `-b` option was added by a Debian patch. The BSD original `ncal` had a `-C` already for that anyway, not sure why they added `-b` on top of that.

Both `-b` and `-C` as well as starting `ncal` as `cal` sets the `flag_backward` flag.

However, when called as `cal`, that is done earlier and in that case, the gregorian switch is [forced to the UK date](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/ncal/ncal.c?view=markup#l255), while it's not done at all for `-C` or `-b`.

That looks like an oversight, but I don't think there's a way around that. The choices you have are:

- call `ncal` as `cal` to get the UK 1752-09-02 switch
- call `ncal -b` or `ncal -C` and don't get a Julian calendar ever

Comment: Hmm looking at the source, it seems that ncal handles options in a strange way. calling with -oC gives you the date of easter, but -Co gives usage info, due to the usage of options.

same for setting nswitchb before processing all options.

It's clear why I get the result I get now, not that I agree it's a sensible thing to do. Probably hasn't been fixed in order to stay backwards compatible I guess. Confusing stuff though